# Terraform: How to retrieve aws s3 access point and s3 access point alias name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have created s3 access point and i have a scenario to create SSM parameters with s3 access point ARN and alias name. I don't see any data source to retrieve the values of s3 access point ARN and s3 alias name.

is there any possibility to retrieve s3 access point arn and alias name from terraform ?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any possibility to retrieve s3 access point arn and alias name from terraform ?

Yes. You have to develop your own, custom data source in a form of an [external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/external).